# Unable to delete User from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to de-active user from my rails application. However, this is not working at the moment.

My routes file -

```
# Root is the unauthenticated path
root 'sessions#unauth'

# Sessions URL
get 'sessions/unauth', to: 'sessions#unauth', as: :login
post 'sessions/login', as: :signin
delete 'sessions/logout', as: :logout

# Resourceful routes for articles
resources :articles
get '/interests', to: 'articles#my_interests', as: 'interests'
get '/destroy', to: 'users#destroy', as: 'destroy_user'
resources :users, only: [:create,:new,:update,:destroy,:edit]
```

Then I have a html file inside layout folder.

```
<li><%= link_to "De-activate User", destroy_user_path(current_user)%></li>
```

User will be clicking De-active User button, and I am expecting action to go into my Users Controller. Below is my UsersController.rb.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update]
  before_action :check_valid, only: [:edit, :destroy, :update]
  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    log_out @user
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to login_path, notice: 'user was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def check_valid
      unless @user==current_user
        redirect_to articles_path
      end
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :bio, :username, :password, :interest_list, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Rails give me error in the set_user method. 
Error - Couldn't find User with 'id'= at  @user = User.find(params[:id])

I am not able to understand what is the issue over here?

My log_out method -

```
def log_out
    session[:user_id] = nil
end
```

Comment: please post `log_out` method

Comment: Rajarshi Das - Pls check now.

Comment: What happens when you place `log_out @user` after `@user.destroy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<li><%= link_to "De-activate User", destroy_user_path(current_user), method: :delete%></li>
```

Thanks

Comment: I did not get this. I have a method called destroy which I am calling by setting a path for destroy in routes file. What will below do? I do not have any method called delete, nor do I have it's route defined.

Comment: here `:delete` is request method type just like `get, put, post etc.` After adding this to the link_to it will call destroy method of your controller as It is used to identified delete request. You don't need to define method delete or adding route for this.

Comment: Get this error: No route matches [DELETE] "/destroy.1"

Comment: Are you using device for authentication? Can you add here your routes.rb?

Comment: Posted in the main post. Pls check.

Comment: I don't think you are doing right? Please add your routes.rb whole file here.

Comment: I have added the whole routes.rb file.

Comment: Modified the routes to this now - delete 'users/destroy', as: :destroy_user

Comment: `delete 'sessions/logout', as: :logout` which controller action it is calling? I think you made it unnecessary complex. Just use devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

You have override your default path that generated by `resources :users` with:

```
get '/destroy', to: 'users#destroy', as: 'destroy_user'
```

If you properly see your built route you can not find `params[:id]`. With this route you can go to action but could not find `params[:id]` there.

You can change your route like this :

```
get '/destroy/:id', to: 'users#destroy', as: 'destroy_user'
```

So your cuurent code will work properly.

Comment: Thanks Dipak. I am getting wrong number of arguments error in log_out method. It is there in my original post. Could you please check, what is wrong over there?

Comment: id problem is sorted though.

Comment: What problem you are getthing ? In your logout action. Seems like it properly setting user_id nil in session

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
<%= link_to "De-activate User", current_user, method: :delete %>
```

OR

```
<%= link_to "De-activate User", user_path(current_user), method: :delete %>
```